# Creating an attribute against WHEREUSED Non Persistent Object - Maximo

Tags: jython, maximo

I have added an attribute against the NP WHEREUSED object.
I'm adding a New Row and the field is getting populated using a LKP and on Save Maximo gets rid of the value.
How can I ensure to maintain the value of the spare fieldon save?

Thanks,

Keepgv

Comment: "using a LKP" ... you mean "using a launch point + autoscript"?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand that it takes code to move anything from a non-persistent (NP) object or attribute to somewhere where it will get saved. Second, you need to understand that the save() method is never called on NP objects; execute() is called instead.

I think the problem you are running into is that Maximo does not currently (as of Maximo 7.6.0.8) offer "Execute" in the selection of events for Object Launch Points. If you would like to see that changed, please vote for this RFE: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=77559

Then, you'll have to find a workaround until IBM implements that RFE.